# Создание, загрузка, сохранение, расчёт диаграмм

Tags: алгоритм

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, наименее трудозатратное решение

Задача: нужна программа для расчёт схем. Схему надо нарисовать, схема состоит из блоков, которые имеют от 1 до 3х выходов, выходы могут возвращаться в начало схемы (схемы могут быть доволньно запутанные). После расчёта схему надо сохранить и иметь возможность загрузить её ,чтобы изменяя исходные данные рассчитать схему заново.

Как мне нарисовать такую схему? Может есть какая-то библиотека, что позволяет рисовать, редактировать блоки (увеличивать их в длину, когда возвраты заставляют графически расширять схему).

Идеальный вариант - нарисовать схему в каком-н внешнем векторном редакторе (например, Inkscape), получить файл из неё, в котором можно будет распознать блоки и связи с другими блокми и произвести расчёт.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то что вы ищите называется "направленный граф"  ("directed-graph", "flow diagram", "flow chart diagram"... ). Библиотек и для численной обработки и отображения, довольно много.

Общеупотребительным форматом хранения графов является [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/). Большинство C++ и Python библиотек работы с графами умеют читать и записывать данные в этом формате.
При этом, собственно, пакет программ graphviz хорош для визуализации графов, но не для их редактирования.

Вторым по полярности форматом является GraphML.

В качестве "внешнего редактора", рекомендую либо текстовый редактор (прямое написание данных на языке graphviz), либо  https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline, либо специализированные "редакторы графов": [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed), [DIA](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/).

Если хотите получить ссылки на популярные библиотеки работы с графами - укажите, хотябы, язык программирования.